# Nested ExpandableListview with only one child should visible at a time

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I am working on a project In which it require two level expandable view and only one child should be open a time. if there is one child and if I click on other child last one should be closed this should happen in both level of Expandable ListView. I have search enough but I didn't find anything good. Any good link and demo will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare variable 
private static int prev = -1;
// and OnGroupExpandListener implement

  mExpandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                if(prev!=-1)
                {

                    mExpandableList.collapseGroup(prev);    

                }
                prev=groupPosition;
            }
        });
```

Comment: but in my childView groupPosition always returns 0.